# Product expression causes features to not render

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl

I have a map with linear features that have an offset in the style:

```
"line-offset": {
  "stops": [ [ 12, 0 ], [ 16, 2 ] ]
},
```

If I try to substitute the value `2` with a [product expression](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#expressions-*), the features fail to render.

```
"line-offset": {
  "stops": [ [ 12, 0 ], [ 16, ["*", 2, 1] ] ]
},
```

There is no error in the javascript console.

I am using the latest version, `v0.49.0`.

Am I using the expression correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use [expressions](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec#expressions), you would need to change the syntax:

```
"line-offset": [
  "interpolate",
  [ "linear" ],
  [ "zoom" ],
  12, 0,
  16, ["*", 2, 1],
]
```